# Create AAR that contain all other AAR dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I'm trying to build an Android Library SDK packaged as AAR.
I'm depending on other companies AAR's as Gradle dependency.

I would like to have a single AAR (mine) that contain all of the other AAR so customers could have a single AAR to integrate with.

How can you package the dependent AAR in to your owns?

(the 3rd party AAR are not publicly available)

Comment: I have the same exact question and I wanted to see if you found a resolution. Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Comment: I found this project userful https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar

Comment: Thank you, @Ika. I was able to accomplish this, see my post here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445399/create-an-aar-with-multiple-aars-jars>

Comment: @AnilGorthy think it's not exactly the same thing. I wanted to be able to deliver a fat AAR while this solves the problem of transitive dependencies (another issue). I'm happy you got things working.

Comment: @lka understood. Just curious if you implemented fat AAR and what your experiences are. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @AnilGorthy I did implement the fat AAR and it worked out just as I expected. I was able to deliver a single AAR that included the 3rd party I used. My customers were able to have a single AAR to integrate with.