# Android Studio : AAR Library dependency inside another AAR Library

Tags: android, dependencies

I am using Android studio 1.5.  I have a library project, **core-speech-service.aar**. This AAR file is generated correctly (all classes are built and packed inside classes.jar in the AAR file).

Now I am creating another AAR library **google-speech-service.aar** which depends on the first AAR (core-speech-service). So I add it as library dependency (compile) in the new AAR library project.

So far, so good.  Android studio copies core-speech-service.aar in to the new library project as a library module. But when I build the google-speech-service library project, it creates an AAR file, but the packed AAR file neither contains classes from the core-speech-service.aar neither it has the core-speech-service.aar itself.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks
abhay

Comment: Any ideas .. Anybody ???

Comment: I came across this [fat aar](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar) link that seemed to help achieve what I was looking at.  Might not be complete solution, but worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to reference the library as an outside dependency on your apk. I believe that as of now you cannot have an aar inside another

Comment: Thanks joseporto .. but this looks like very basic requirement .. and used to work well in eclipse world ..

Comment: possibilities are there. just refer this link creating AAR inside aar,jar. and how to use that Main AAR to third party application.                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445399/create-an-aar-with-multiple-aars-jars