# How to add Google vision dependencies to my .aar?

Tags: java, android, vision, google-vision

I am creating an android library (.aar) that is using the Google android vision Gradle dependencies for OCRing. But I am unable to figure out how should I can add the Gradle dependency to the .aar File.

I don't want to add Google dependency separately while using my .aar because my library project already contains the same.

I have tried one solution by pushing the .aar file to local maven then using the same in the application but in that case I was still unable to find the Google Vision classes to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@user3572586, same issue faced, when you build aar file only project source added in aar not dependency lib. so you need to add externally.

Or

You need to publish your aar in maven repository (local or remote) and including it using compile (...@aar) transitive dependencies are turned off.

For more info see link below's,

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749728/how-to-specify-dependencies-in-aar-library)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177346/android-studio-aar-library-dependency-inside-another-aar-library/36444387)

Comment: I am trying the 2nd solution (using local maven). I have included the gradle dependency in .aar file and then published the .aar file to local maven. After that including it using compile (...@aar) transitive dependencies are turned On.  
But I am still unable to Get the classes of the Google Vision in the application.